# More structs/classes for better naming convention or not?

Tags: c++, struct, naming-conventions

I have input data like below,

```
//road graph: from and to
1 2
1 3
3 4
3 5
//next festive city: type and city_id
2 5
2 3
1 3
2 3
2 4
```

So far, I make 1 struct to represent both input types.

```
struct MainData{
    int data;
    int data_1;
};

int main()
{
    /*code omitted*/
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        cin>> highWays[i].data >> highWays[i].data_1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>queries[i].data>>queries[i].data_1;
    }
    /*code omitted*/
}
```

IMO, I don't think it's a good pratice, since the purpose of `data` and `data_1` is not clear. Though adding another struct might introduce larger file. Therefore, I'm confused whether to make 2 structs to differentiate those input types, which leads to better naming convention, or not. Any advice?

Comment: We would need some more information on what the values in the file are actually supposed to _mean_. And in any case, `data` and `data_1` are very useless names. How about something like `source` and `target`, if the file lines are supposed to represent graph edges?

Comment: Start off by writing clear, maintainable code.  Then when you are done profile and see if you need to change things from there.  You would be surprised by the amount of optimizations a compiler can code with good, easy to understand code.

Comment: @NathanOliver `the amount of optimizations a compiler can code with good, easy to understand code` Can you give an example for that? Not quite understand here

Comment: @Bla... Sorry I had a typo meant to say *the amount of optimizations a compiler can do with good, easy to understand code*.  Take for example the fact that `foo <<= 1;` is the same as `foo *= 2;` with the former being more efficient but the latter is much easier to understand.  A good compiler being able to understand what you want to do can make the later just as efficient as the former.  See [this](https://godbolt.org/g/BhWV1Z) example and you will see that compiler generates the same code but `simple` is a lot easier to read and understand then `complex`.

Answer (score 3):

> adding another struct might introduce larger file.

If this helps readability, it is a very good tradeoff. Adding another `struct` to aid readability does not increase the size of your compiled program.

`struct`s are primarily a compile-time artifact. The compiler uses them to know the size and field offsets. Unless your `struct` comes with virtual member functions, adding a new `struct` does not increase your program's run-time footprint. In cases when your `struct`s are completely unrelated, there is no memory or CPU penalty for separating them out.

When your `struct`s are related, though, C++ lets you have the best of both worlds: make a base class, derive from it, and provide member functions with descriptive names:

```
class GraphEdge {
protected:
    int from;
    int to;
    GraphEdge(int f, int t) : from(f), to(t) {}
};

struct RoadEdge : public GraphEdge {
    int fromRoad() { return from; }
    int toRoad() { return to; }
    RoadEdge(int f, int t) : GraphEdge(f, t) {}
};

struct CityEdge : public GraphEdge {
    int fromCity() { return from; }
    int toCity() { return to; }
    CityEdge(int f, int t) : GraphEdge(f, t) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case for the latter input type is not `from` and `to`, but more like `type` and `city_id`, see updated question. So your code above doesn't fit my need. However, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very clear case: You are reading two very different tuples from your file(s).  The first list contains *graph edges* with source and target indices, while the second list contains *cities* with a type and an ID.

You should be worrying about the readability, understandability and maintainability of your code first and foremost.  The compiler will be able to optimize plenty; it is fairly unlikely that you will gain anything from the kind of premature optimization you are thinking of.  So, following @dasblinkenlight's good answer (which he wrote before you enlightened us about the purpose of your data structures), I would recommend two different data structures:

```
class GraphEdge {
protected:
    int from;
    int to;
    GraphEdge(int f, int t) : from(f), to(t) {}
};

class FestiveCity {
protected:
    int city_type; // This should probably be an enum
    int id;
    FestiveCity(int t, int i) : city_type(t), id(i) {}
};
```